# Como substituir um caractere por outro na coluna “Semana1” do datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Quero trocar “R$” por “R$ 0,00”, mas tem dado erro.

```
        private void FrmTrimestre3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DgvCalculo();
            PersonalizarDGV();
        }
       
         private void PersonalizarDGV()
        {
  
            // largura das colunas
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[0].Width = 64;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[1].Width = 105;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[2].Width = 64;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[3].Width = 105;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[4].Width = 64;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[5].Width = 105;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[6].Width = 64;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[7].Width = 105;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[8].Width = 64;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[9].Width = 105;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[10].Width = 64;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[11].Width = 105;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dgviewPersonalizado12.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12F, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        }
       
         private void DgvAlterar()
        {
          

           try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dcalculo2.Rows)
                {

                    if (this.Text != "")
                    {
                        row.Cells["Semana1"].Value = this.Text;
                        //row.Cells["Semana1"].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
                        row.Cells["Semana1"].Value.ToString().Replace("R$", "");
                        row.Cells["Semana1"].Value.ToString().Replace(".", "");
                        row.Cells["Semana1"].Value.ToString().Trim();
                        this.Text = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Semana1"].Value).ToString("c");

                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                this.Text = "R$ 0,00";
            }
                            
        }



 private void DgvCalculo()

        {
            var dcalculo = dgviewPersonalizado12;  

   
dgviewPersonalizado12.AutoGenerateColumns = false;



            dgviewPersonalizado12.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;

            dgviewPersonalizado12.ColumnCount = 12;

            dgviewPersonalizado12.RowCount = 7;
            
            // Nome das colunas
            dcalculo.Columns[0].Name = "Data0";
            dcalculo.Columns[1].Name = "Semana1";
            dcalculo.Columns[2].Name = "Data1";
            dcalculo.Columns[3].Name = "Semana2";
            dcalculo.Columns[4].Name = "Data2";
            dcalculo.Columns[5].Name = "Semana3";
            dcalculo.Columns[6].Name = "Data3";
            dcalculo.Columns[7].Name = "Semana4";
            dcalculo.Columns[8].Name = "Data4";
            dcalculo.Columns[9].Name = "Semana5";
            dcalculo.Columns[10].Name = "Data5";
            dcalculo.Columns[11].Name = "Semana6";

            // data hora     
            dcalculo.Columns["Data0"].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
            dcalculo.Columns["Data0"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MMM";

            // valor monetário
            dcalculo.Columns["Semana1"].ValueType = typeof(double);
            dcalculo.Columns["Semana1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";


            double total2 = 0;
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dcalculo.Rows)
                {

                    if (row.Cells["Semana1"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        total2 += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Semana1"].Value);

                    }

                    label20.Text = total2.ToString("c");
                }
            }
            catch 
            {

                label20.Text = "";
            }
            

        }


private void dgviewPersonalizado12_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

        {

            DgvAlterar();
            DgvCalculo();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

se deseja formatar uma coluna tente isso:

dcalculo.Columns["Semana1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Boa noite Samuel e muito obrigado pela dica, se eu não conseguir resolver o problema de trocar  "R$" por "R$ 0,00" ao sair da célula da coluna "Semana1", acabarei adotando a sua dica.